# What is removing my headers in PHP/Apache2?

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm using PHP 5.3 and Apache 2.0 to serve a script which adds a number of headers to the output:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Last-Modified: $lastmode"); // $lastmod = Tue, 01 Mar 2011 14:56:22 +0000
header("Etag: $etag"); // Etag = 5da02274fcad09a55f4d74467f66a864
```

Now, all the headers come through except for the `Last-Modified` and `Etag`. In my httpd.conf I have the following:

```
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Pragma
```

But in my response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 16:49:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (EL) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

My `Last-Modified` and `Etag` headers are gone and we have `Cache-Control` and `Expires` in their place.

I should also mention that I have disabled `mod_expires` to no avail. I am pulling my hair out at this point as no matter what I do the headers are simply not there. What could possibly cause them to be removed?

Thanks,
J

UPDATE: It seems that Apache is adding the additional headers after PHP has shutdown and I would think it's also removing the headers I set above. Registering a shutdown function in PHP and calling `apache_response_headers` shows:

```
Pragma=
Expires=  
Etag=5da02274fcad09a55f4d74467f66a864
Last-Modified=Tue, 01 Mar 2011 14:56:22 +0000
Keep-Alive=timeout=15, max=8000
Connection=Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding=chunked
Content-Type=application/json
```

Comment: What values are `$lastmode` and `$etag`?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question to show the values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question it seems that the tool I was using to debug was giving me the grief. It was the mod_expires module causing the problem in the first place but the reason that removing it had no effect was that the proxy I was using to debug the problem (Charles) seems to modify the headers. Once Charles was taken out of the loop my headers were there!